# How do I successfully remove Gnome Panels 12.04LTS?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gnome-panel, gconf, dconf

So I have read many threads on various forums and tried all the prescribed key combinations to remove a panel.

I have tried installing both `dconf-editor` and `gconf-editor` to change the key located at `/desktop/gnome/session/required_components` but the key does not exist, or is just not showing up in the editors, not sure.

Have also tried using  `killall gnome-panel` but there is no running process by this name.

I have also tried using the following command in terminal:
`gconftool-2 --type=string --set /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/panel 'avant-window-navigator'`, but it only created a key and made no changes to the system.

I am a bit new to linux so there is probably something I am missing, but I cannot find it.  I am running 12.04LTS and have tried all of these methods after logging into both "Gnome" and "Gnome Classic" sessions.

Comment: last reply works @StephenMyall so yes a duplicate though a warning to all: the rest of that topic will not be useable for 12.04+